# Meteor.js collection aggregate returning undefined is not a function

Tags: meteor

I am trying to make collection aggregate in my Meteor.js app as shown below, yet each time I call my server logSummary method I get the following error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong / how to resolve this error? Thanks.

Note: I am using [Meteor-aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate) package

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Template.detailedreport.helpers.myCollection (http://localhost:3000/client/views/report.js?
```

Code:

```
Template.detailedreport.rendered = function() {
     Session.set("dreport_customer", "");
     Session.set("dreport_project", "");
     Session.set("dreport_startDate", new Date());
     Session.set("dreport_endDate", new Date());

   $('.set-start-date').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        defaultDate: new Date()
   });
   $('.set-end-date').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        defaultDate: new Date()
   });  

  $('.set-start-date').on("dp.change",function (e) {
       Session.set("dreport_startDate", $('.set-start-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString());
    });
    $('.set-end-date').on("dp.change",function (e) {
        Session.set("dreport_endDate", $('.set-end-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString());
    });
};

Template.detailedreport.helpers({
    customerslist: function() {
       return Customers.find({}, {sort:{name: -1}});       
    },
    projectslist: function() { 
       return Projects.find({customerid: Session.get("dreport_customer")}, {sort:{title: -1}});       
    },
    myCollection: function () {
      var now  = Session.get("dreport_startDate");
      var then = Session.get("dreport_endDate");
      var custID = Session.get("dreport_customer");
      var projID = Session.get("dreport_project");
          Meteor.call('logSummary', now, then, projID, custID, function(error, data){
            if(error)
              return alert(error.reason);
            return data;
          });        

    },      
    settings: function () {
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showFilter: true,
            showColumnToggles: false,
            fields: [
                { key: '0._id.day', label: 'Day' },
                { key: '0.totalhours', label: 'Hours Spent'}                           
            ]
        };
    }

});

Template.detailedreport.events({
   'submit form': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

  Session.set('dreport_endDate', $('.set-end-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString());
  Session.set('dreport_startDate', $('.set-start-date').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString());
  Session.set('dreport_project', $(e.target).find('[name=project]').val());
  Session.set('dreport_customer', $(e.target).find('[name=customer]').val());      

   },  
   'change #customer': function(e){
        Session.set("dreport_project", "");
    Session.set("dreport_customer", e.currentTarget.value);
   },
   'change #project': function(e){
    Session.set("dreport_project", e.currentTarget.value);
   }  
});



Template:

    <div>
      {{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover" collection=myCollection settings=settings}}
    </div>




Server:

Meteor.methods({
  logSummary: function(startDate, endDate, projid, custid){
    var pipeline = [
      { $match: { date: { $gte: new Date(startDate), $lte: new Date(endDate) },
                  projectid: projid,
                  customerid: custid
                } 
      },
      { $group: {
            _id: { 
                "projectid": "$projectid",
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" },
                "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                "year": { "$year": "$date" }
            },
            totalhours: {"$sum": "$hours"}
       }}
    ];
    return ProjectLog.aggregate(pipeline);;
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a SyntaxError in `myCollection` helper. If I am counting right, there's one additional curly brace.

Comment: @apendua Sorry that was a typo mistake while I was writing the question, removed it. In the app code that wasn't there

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the ReactiveTable documentation, it looks like you need to do something like:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    myCollection: function () {
        return myCollection;
    }
});
```

Where myCollection is the name of a Mongo/Meteor collection (e.g. BlogPosts) which you defined with e.g. `BlogPosts = new Mongo.Collection('blogPosts');`

The reason you're getting `undefined is not a function` is that you are calling a Meteor method inside a template helper. The call is **asynchronous** so the return value is `undefined`. Now you are passing `undefined` to ReactiveTable. ReactiveTable will be trying to call something like `myCollection.find()` which is essentially `undefined.find()` and will therefore throw the error you're seeing.

Later on the Meteor call will finish and the `data` value will be lost because the function has already returned.

You can call `Meteor.call` inside the onCreated function like so:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.call('myFunction', 'my', 'params', function (err, result) {
        if (err) { 
            // do something about the error
        } else {
            Session.set('myData',result);
        }
    });
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    myData: function () {
        Session.get('myData')
    }
});
```

This won't fix the issue with ReactiveTable, however.

If the collection you're trying to display is only used for this single page, you could put the aggregation inside the publish function so that minimongo contains ***only*** the documents that match the aggregation and therefore the correct documents will appear in your ReactiveTable.